# How can I get multiple different images on one page in Lightroom's custom print layouts?

Tags: lightroom, printing, lightroom-4

In the print section of Lightroom, it's possible to create your own photo packages or sheets with for example, three images on a single page. I love this feature but have always had one problem that I'm sure is fixable.

In my last example I wanted to create a page with 4 x wallet sized images. I added 4 boxes of the correct dimensions to the page and dragged over an image onto one of them.

The issue is that all of the boxes with populated with the same image. When dragging another onto one of the other boxes, it once again duplicated them.

How can I setup these pages with different images on the same sheet (like the standard Lightroom layouts)?

Comment: In the Filmstrip, select the 4 images you want (Ctrl/Cmd click).

Comment: @ElendilTheTall So how do I place them in the correct boxes? Like I said, when I drag one over a box, it places it in all boxes.

Comment: I don't think you can - it just puts them in in the order they appear in the strip. If you want more flexibility, you'll need to use Photoshop (or GIMP). Just set up a template with guides, export the images from Lightroom at the correct size, drag and drop. Not quite as convenient, but it will do the job.

Comment: After a quick check, you _can_ go to the Book module, choose a 2 x 2 template, and drag photos to whatever slot you want. The only problem is (and this seems to be a massive oversight on Adobe's part) is that you are forced to choose from a fixed selection of book sizes that you can't alter. Maybe export the page as a large JPEG and crop it for printing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce the undesired behaviour in LR5.

It happens when the `layout style` (top most category) "Picture Package" is selected.
Whatever you do, all boxes of one page are filled with the same image.
I think the point of this layout style is exactly that: create a layout with different sized boxes to get one image printed at all those sizes.

To get different images on the same page, using the `layout style` "Custom Package" worked for me.

Comment: The problem isn't getting different images on the page, it's being able to position them.

Comment: connersz stated that `it places it in all boxes`, which to me sounds like placing different images on one page is indeed the problem.

Comment: Actually this was the answer I was looking for. I did manage to figure this out in the end last night but have marked this as an answer regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy, actually. Just select your template, whether Lightroom's 'Picture Package' or your own 'Custom Package', then drag the desired photos up from the film strip.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do this the other day for printing some photos for someone. I couldn't work out how to do it. I went to Photoshop because I used to be able to do a contact sheet there, but since CS4 I think it has been added as a feature in Adobe Bridge instead.

In Bridge, I think you go into `Output` mode, and should see options on the right hand side. Here you can choose a number of rows and columns, spacing between them etc etc, when you choose PDF as the output format. There are also template options. There is a video on how to do it here:

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-contact-sheet-cs5.html

By the way, if you have Lightroom installed, then Adobe Bridge is probably either installed already or if you are using Lightroom CC, you should be able to log in to your account and I think it might be installable without any extra cost

Comment: That will achieve contact sheets but what about if you are printing multiple different sized images on one sheet? I'm also looking for a way to do it in Lightroom. I'm sure it's available, as their own templates include said feature.

Comment: @connersz What if you create custom boxes first, then drag and drop an image from the film strip into one of the boxes? I might have gone to Bridge because of the amount of images that I had to add rather than because it wasn't possible; I will have to have a go when I'm at home this evening

Comment: Like I said before, I have tried that.

Comment: @connersz is it Lightroom 5 that you are using? I've just found this https://www.rmsp.com/blog/2014/09/04/printing-multiple-photos-page-using-lightroom-5/ showing some of the presets allow you to use multiple images. I use LR 4 at the moment but I've installed LR5 for testing. I'll take a look when I get back